# Reading and returning the HTML content from a specified URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, http

I wanted to create a simple function that can read and return the HTML content from a specified URL. This is what reading here and there lead me to:

```
from socket import timeout
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError

def get_html_content(url, max_attempt = 3):
    req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    content = ""
    attempt = 1
    while True:
        try:
            html_page = urlopen(req, timeout=10)
            content = html_page.read()
        except (HTTPError, URLError, timeout) as e:
            if isinstance(e, HTTPError):
                print("The server couldn\'t fulfill the request....attempt %d/%d" % (attempt, max_attempt))
                print('Error code: ', e.code)
            if isinstance(e, URLError):
                print("We failed to reach a server....attempt %d/%d" % (attempt, max_attempt))
                print('Reason: ', e.reason)
            if isinstance(e, timeout):
                print('timeout...attempt %d/%d' % (attempt, max_attempt))
            attempt += 1
            if attempt > max_attempt:
                break
            continue
        else:
            break

    return content
```

I would use this function to parse the content of many URLs. For `if content = ""`, I would raise a random exception after writing to some file whatever I had already successfully gathered.

Comment: you may want to consider using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), possibly with an extension to account for the multiple attempts, or just iterating as you did)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple of minor technical issues:

- The `content` variable is unnecessary, because you can simply return `html_page.read()` directly. (And you could as well return `urlopen(req, timeout=10).read()` directly...) When the max attempts are reached, you could `return ""` instead of relying on that `content` was initialized to `""`. And how about returning `None`? Then you could simply omit the `return` statement to the same effect.
- In the exception handling, there are multiple `if` statements with conditions that are mutually exclusive, only one can match at a time. In such situation you should chain them together with `elif`.
- Instead of doing a single `except` statement with multiple error types and then using conditionals to identify the correct one, it would be better to use multiple `except` statements each with a single error type.
- You could iterate using `range` for slightly more compact code.

Like this:

```
def get_html_content(url, max_attempt = 3):
    req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

    for attempt in range(max_attempt):
        try:
            return urlopen(req, timeout=10).read()
        except HTTPError as e:
            print("The server couldn\'t fulfill the request....attempt {}/{}".format(attempt + 1, max_attempt))
            print('Error code: ', e.code)
        except URLError as e:
            print("We failed to reach a server....attempt {}/{}".format(attempt + 1, max_attempt))
            print('Reason: ', e.reason)
        except timeout as e:
            print('timeout...attempt {}/{}'.format(attempt + 1, max_attempt))
```